# Is it possible to have two gridbag layouts side-by-side inside a frame?

Tags: java, gridbaglayout

I'm using an extended JFrame class, called MFrame, to initialize two objects that extend JPanel. One JPanel has buttons, called ButtonPanel, and the other has a tree generated via reading in XML file, called TreePanel. I'd like to have them in two separate classes because I'll be adding a lot of functionality and I want to have them be as minimal as possible.

Inside both ButtonPane and TreePanel, gridbag is used to establish layout. I'm trying to display both within the same JFrame,  but whichever one is added last, via ex. this.add(ButtonPanel), covers up the JPanel class behind it.

Has anyone been able to display two JPanel classes with Gridbag side-by-side within a JFrame? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how:

- Create a MPanel and add it to MFrame
- Set its Layout to BoxLayout (horizontal in your case)
- Add the TreePanel and ButtonPanel MPanel

You have to add a Panel because the default for `JFrame` is `BorderLayout` so `add(...)` is essentialy the same as `add(..., BorderLayout.CENTER)` thus only the last componet you add is visible.